# Postgresql : Replace All Words In Single Field Value

Tags: arrays, postgresql, replace, split

I have data from my table such as

```
customers_name
ABCC DEFG HIJK
CDEE FGHI JKLMN
```

I want to transform value in any words separated by space to

```
customers_name
AB## DE## HI##
CD## FG## JKL##
```

for marking Customers Name.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve? And what are the names of your columns.

Comment: I have column "customer_name" that store the real name like this
Johnny Depp 
Al Pacino 
Robert De Niro 
Kevin Spacey 
Denzel Washington 
Russell Crowe
Brad Pitt 


My requirement is to show only first 3 character and change remain of each word of customer_name by replace with some character like '#'. My needed output is   

Joh### Dep# 
Al Pac### 
Rob### De Nir# 
Kev## Spa### 
Den### Was####### 
Rus#### Cro##
Bra# Pit# 

Thank you.